# Will IPv6 make shared IPs obsolete?

Tags: ipv6

Most ISPs in my area almost exclusively use shared IPv4 addresses; I gather that this is forced by the IPv4 exhaustion.

Is this the only reason? Will IPv6 eliminate the need for shared IPs?

After some comment I realized that I had not specified that my focus is on typical home internet and not business oriented; so the question is not whether will NAT still be useful but whether ISP will offer them in the base packages.

Comment: That was the original plan for IPv6. Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: Need? yes. Desire? no. NAT has often been billed as a technology for fighting address-space exhaustion, but as it is commonly implemented with stateful packet filtering, it provides a very useful mechanism for basic network security and privacy for folks that don't want expensive and complicated infrastructure (eg everyone who doesn't get paid to setup and maintain such networks). I would certainly never exchange my RFC1918 LAN for a clump of IPv6 addresses  and in the process expose every device on my network, with no meaningful way to filter inbound or outbound centrally.

Comment: @FrankThomas I fail to see what your point is. If all traffic is passing through a device, that device can call itself "NAT" or "firewall" or "shoebox" for all I care. You can't have NAT without the *effect* of some kind of stateful firewalling, but that's merely a side effect of how NAT works. With IPv6, suddenly we get back to the option of true end to end connectivity with firewalling if desired but *without* address translation. You wouldn't hook an IPv6-native system directly to the Internet any more than you would (should) an IPv4-native system. Please keep NAT and firewalling distinct.

Comment: I hear what you are saying, but OP is asking about "Shared IPs" which means the perspective of the WAN side of a NAT, and IP version doesn;t really factor in at all except from an exhaustion perspective. I use NAT not because of exhaustion but for the reasons I stated above. In an IPv6 world we no longer need sharedIPs/NAT, but we still want them.

Comment: Relevant: [With IPv6, should we be assigning distinct IP addresses to each host name served over HTTP(S)?](https://serverfault.com/q/785394/58408) on [sf]. (Full disclosure: It is my own question.)

Comment: "so the question is not whether will NAT still be useful but whether ISP will offer them in the base packages." - This is not possible for us to predict.  An ISP will do whatever makes the most business sense.

Answer (score 2):

> I gather that this is forced by the IPv4 exhaustion.
>   Is this the only reason?

It is the only valid reason.

Since sharing one more more IPs (NAT/PAT) also needs a firewall to do the translation it is now also considered more secure. Ofc. just adding the firewall without using NAT/PAT accomplishes the same.

> Will IPv6 eliminate the need for shared IPs?

Yes. IP v4 addressspace exhaustion was one of the reason we now have IP v6 (since about 2 decades, though rollout is slow).  It also adds other advantages, such as better header design. But address space exhaustion is why we need IPv6.